# Excel Q - SUMIFS with a 2 dimensional array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a 2-D array: dates on a horizontal axis and identification numbers on a vertical axis.

I want the sums conditioned on a particular date and ID, and I want to know how to do this using SUMIFS.

For some reason, it seems like I cannot since the array is 2-D while the criteria ranges are 1-D. Can anyone give me any advice on other formulas I can use?

In other words, I would like to add the values that satisfy the ID and date I select; there is one or more data point that satisfies the conditions. This is why the SUMIF function is relevant.

Comment: examples of data or formula,,,

Comment: Are the dates and ID numbers unique? If so, are you looking for a formula to return the unique intersection of a date/ID number? Just confused since you asked for a SUM solution, which implies to me that you're finding more than one result.

Answer (score 17):

With this data you will not be able to use a SUMIF forumula. Here's a formula you can use:

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$6=C9,IF($F$1:$K$1=B9,$F$2:$K$6)))
```

Change the addresses where appropriate and be sure and enter it by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. You can also use the below formula to avoid pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6=C9)*($F$1:$K$1=B9)*$F$2:$K$6)
```

[image]

Comment: The formula now takes into account that there might be multiple ID's or dates.

Comment: I have done this but I am getting a VALUE error. My data is slightly different from yours in that there are some columns of other data between the ID and the rest of the data in your sheet (Columns C-H). Should this make a difference?

Comment: i would go for the sumproduct too, it is a bit hard to understand but once you do that is so powerfull. You can add as many criterias as you wish.

Comment: Do those "other columns" need to be included in the total? Or can we just build the formula around them?

Comment: i would suggest to include them, the tricky part with sumproducts is to well define your area.

Comment: rwilson: the other columns do not need to be accounted for in the total, but they cannot be removed.

Comment: Ok. I made the updates. Just don't include those columns in the formula.

Comment: sumproduct actually works! nice. sum(if(if did not work for me, though. thanks

Comment: @mourad. I prefer the SUMPRODUCT formula also, but normally it's tougher to understand. My boss rolled his eyes the last time I mentioned boolean algebra.

Comment: @wilson, you should be the boss then ;-) i feel clever when i do sumproducts.

Comment: @Joseph Kadoch. Glad the sumproduct formula worked for you. The other formula should work as long as you enter it with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Can you close this question?

Comment: The other "array formula" can be used for many other functions. Furthermore multiple conditions can be "ANDED" together by placing a bracket and multiplying (($F$1:$K$1=B9)*($F$1:$K$1<B10)) for example.

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed a 2D conditional array function but didn't realize, as you have shown, that one needs to nest the conditions for one dimension inside the the conditions for the second, with two separate if statements.

Comment: @JosephKadoch the #VALUE error can occur if you have any text in your data range.  blank cells are ok but one text character in the entire range will throw it off.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're looking for an intersection of an ID and a Date, you can use the following:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH([ID Number],A:A,0),MATCH([Date],1:1,0)))`

`INDIRECT` allows you to type in an address as plain text and returns the value

`ADDRESS` turns the numbers for rows and columns into a regular address

`MATCH` finds where in a row or column a given value is located.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add that the array version of the 2D summation in the answer above

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$6=C9,IF($F$1:$K$1=B9,$F$2:$K$6)))
```

will work better if your data table $F$2:$K$6 has blanks (or other non-numeric values) because it will sum only the values that match criteria specified by $B$2:$B$6=C9 $F$1:$K$1=B9 and ignore all others.

Generally, you probably will not have blanks or other non-numeric values in your data table but I just wanted to throw this out there in case it helps someone. It certainly helped me, and I had fun playing with both 2D summation examples above. :)