# Multiple Sumrange in SUMIFS excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to use SUMIFS in excel. I was thinking I can select the multiple cell for one sumrange criteria `(SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], …))` in different column by pressing Ctrl+select but its not the case. When I am selecting like this, its adding comma and going to another criteria.  I can able to achieve this by adding multiple sumifs like `=sumifs() + sumifs ()` to achieve what I need. I wrote the working formula as

```
=SUMIFS('Daily Log Sheet'!E3:E63, 'Daily Log Sheet'!B3:B63, 'Monthly Record'!B4) + SUMIFS('Daily Log Sheet'!E74:E144, 'Daily Log Sheet'!B74:B144, 'Monthly Record'!B4)
```

Instead of using multiple sumifs statement, is there any way to select multiple cell in different column in one criteria. Like by adding `&` operator in one criteria. I tried this but not working.

Its taking a lot of time in writing multiple sumifs statement and I have many sheets to work on. There is any way to select multiple cell in one criteria.

Comment: Could you use sumifs and filter out the ranges that you want to skip using a second condition?

Comment: Sorry I edited the sumifs syntax. I am using sumifs only but its not working. I want to use muliple sum_range in one sumifs.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use multiple sum range in the same formula? There might be a better way

Comment: @LJ01, I have to omit some cells in between the coloum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT will allow you to exclude rows 64:73.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Daily Log Sheet'!B3:B144='Monthly Record'!B4)*((ROW($3:$144)<64)+(ROW($3:$144)>73)), 'Daily Log Sheet'!E3:E144)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its exactly I need.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the **`SUMIF`** *and* **`SUMIFS` Functions** are:

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])

SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], …)
```

... regardless of whether it's being used in an array formula.

The number of parameters in a function do not change just because it's being used in an array formula.

Parameters shown in **`[` square brackets `]`** are optional.  If there's more than one criterion within the *same set* of `[` square brackets `]` —  like `[criteria_range2, criteria2]` — then they *all* must be included *or* excluded *together*.

Outside of that, you can't arbitrarily add or remove parameters from functions.

---

### More information:

- Office.com : [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)
- Office.com : [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)
- Stack Overflow : [SUMIFS with a 2 dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31506004/8112776)
- Office.com : [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: Sorry I edited my text. I alrady used sumifs as per your syntax but its not working. I want to use multiple sum_range with different colomn.

Comment: Summing multiple ranges will require multiple formulas, which can *then* be summed.  *Named Ranges* **do** work with these functions, but not if they span multiple areas.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, and can't test it on my phone but you might be able to use a standard sum() function, and an if as an array formula....

```
=Sum(if({criteria_range1}={criteria1},{sum range1},if{criteria_range2}={criteria2},{sum range 2})
```